# Java8 ObjectProperty in a TableView does not refresh

Tags: java, properties, javafx

I have this TableView of People:

```
<TableView fx:id="table" editable="true" focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="false" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" resizable="false" sortable="false" style="-fx-font-size: 13pt;" text="Address">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="id" />
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="200.0" resizable="false" sortable="false" style="-fx-font-size: 13pt;" text="Address Type">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="range" />
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn editable="false" prefWidth="200.0" resizable="false" sortable="false" style="-fx-font-size: 13pt;" text="Timestamp">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="timestamp" />
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

And the Class People:

```
public class People {  
public static enum Range {ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR}

public People() {
}

private IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
public int getId() {
    return id.get();
}
public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id.set(id);
}

private ObjectProperty<Range> range = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
public Range getRange() {
    return range.get();
}
public ObjectProperty<Range> rangeProperty() {
    return range;
}
public void setRange(Range range) {
    this.range.set(range);
}

private ObjectProperty<Timestamp> timestamp = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp.get();
}
public ObjectProperty<Timestamp> timestampProperty() {
    return timestamp;
}
public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.timestamp.set(timestamp);
}
}
```

My problem is that when i set a new TimeStamp in a people row and the TableView is showed up, the column does not update the Timestamp. I have to use StringProperties to auto-refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got the solution.

I was updating the timestamp in this way:

```
private Timestamp actualTimestamp = new Timestamp();
private void updateTimeStamp(){
  actualTimestamp.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
  people.setTimestamp(actualTimestamp);
}
```

The not-refreshing reason: I'm not setting a new Timestamp object, so the invalidation does not weak up.

**Correct way:**

```
private void updateTimeStamp(){
  actualTimestamp.setTime(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
  people.setTimestamp(actualTimestamp);
}
```